# Chrome extension set to `run_at` `document_start` is running too fast?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts, content-script

EDIT: Something was wrong with my Chrome browser and creating a conflict with my script, a full reinstall eliminated whatever the problem source was. If I happen to find out what was causing it I will include it in here.

EDIT2: Just to let anyone reading this in 2017 know that I haven't forgotten this and I have never had this problem since my previous edit.

EDIT3: It is 2019 and so far I've never had this problem again.

---

I have been learning how to create a simple Chrome extension which is a userscript port. The script works perfectly with Tampermonkey with the setting `run at` to `document-start`, all the necessary events that need to be caught from the beginning are all captured.

However, when I set the same settings in the Chrome extension I discovered that the same running setting is faster than Tampermonkey's which causes the first function to fail: (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null.`) since it tries to append a script element to the `head` section, which doesn't exist until 0.010s later.

My dirty solution so far has been to make use of a `setInterval` function with the timer set to 10 to check if `document.head` exists and then proceed with the code if the condition is true.

Is there any way that I can make this work correctly without having to resort to `setInterval` or maybe replicate Tampermonkey's `grant none` option which appears to run the userscript on the webpage context?

The following is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js":        [ "simpleuserscript.user.js" ],
        "matches":   [ "https://www.google.com/*"],
        "run_at":    "document_start"
    } ],
    "converted_from_user_script": true,
    "description":  "Chrome extension",
    "name":         "Testing",
    "version":      "1"
}
```

All of this could be avoided if Chrome would adopt the `afterscriptexecute` event, but until that happens I am stuck with the `load` event. I thank in advance any help provided.

---

EDIT: I have already tried the suggestions in the replies: using a different `run at` point, using `DOMContentLoaded` and append to `document.documentElement`. All were unsuccessful because: 1 and 2 makes the script miss early events, and 3 returns the same TypeError as when trying to append to `document.head`.

The script has to be inserted/running when `document.readyState = loading` or else it will miss early necessary events, but not so early to the point of being unable to append childs to either `documentElement`or `head`

An example of the code inside `simpleuserscript.user.js`:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "console.log('success')";
if(document.head) {
    document.head.appendChild(script);
} else if(document.documentElement) {
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}
```

Console will show `TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Chrome extension *Content scripts* (run from a `manifest.json`) that are run at `document_start`, *do* fire before [`document.readyState`<sup>Doc</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState) has reached `interactive` -- which is the earliest you want to start messing with most page elements.

However, you can inject most `<script>` nodes right away if you wish.  Just not to `document.head` or `document.body` because they don't exist yet.
Append to `documentElement` instead. For example:

```
var s = document.createElement ("script");
s.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js";
s.async = false;
document.documentElement.appendChild (s);
```

Or

```
var s = document.createElement ("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL ("MyPwnCode.js");
s.async = false;
document.documentElement.appendChild (s);
```

---

If you are adding or modifying *other* DOM elements, in a script running at `document_start`, wait until the `DOMContentLoaded` event like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fireContentLoadedEvent, false);

function fireContentLoadedEvent () {
    console.log ("DOMContentLoaded");
    // PUT YOUR CODE HERE.
    //document.body.textContent = "Changed this!";
}
```

Comment: I saw a lot of negative replies so just want to say I was playing around with this for a long time and most of the erroneous results were because I was testing the script with the developer console open which seems to give a different result to when it's closed. I got it to work, injecting jquery source script into pages from an alternative source, I'm in China so Google CDN is blocked, and I used run_at document_start and documentElement to append the script node and it works fine. A little delayed as it tries to load the other script too I may work on this later but for now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Your problem is that, when using `"run_at": "document_start"`, the only element that is granted to exist in the DOM is the `<html>` element. If you want to avoid errors relative to page load, like trying to access some element that hasn't been created yet, you'll have to either:

- Make your script run at `"document_idle"` or `"document_end"`. Although `"document_end"` still doesn't grant you that all the elements and resources of the page have been fully loaded (but the DOM has already been parsed), the `"document_idle"` keyword will give you the certainty that the DOM has been parsed and all the elements and resources have been loaded properly before your script runs.
- Or, instead, you can continue using `"document_start"` wrapping your code inside a `"DOMContentLoaded"` listener, which will make it run when the DOM has completely finished loading and parsing, similarly to `"document_idle"`. Here's an example:

  ```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      // Run your code here...
  });
  ```

Comment: `document_idle` happens **after** `document_end`

Comment: @Xan quoting from the doc: "In the case of document_idle, the browser chooses a time to inject scripts between document_end and immediatly after the window.onload event fires [...]" so am I reading wrong or..?

Comment: You're reading it right, but `window.onload` happens after `document_end`. `window.onload` implies [all resources have been loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload), and `document_end` fires already after DOM is complete (which is earlier).

Comment: Using `document_idle`or `document_end` make the script load too late, making it unable to capture early events.

Using `DOMContentLoaded` yields the same problems, the script is inserted/run too late.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, But couldn't some other script on the page itself remove your listener? Thus using document_idle is better?

Comment: @Xan, If `document_start` is inserted after the last `<style></style>`, and `document_end` is inserted in `DOMContentLoaded`, Doesn't that mean that if we do not use `document_start`, [`DOMContentLoaded` will not wait for `<style></style>`](http://archive.is/wk5rW#selection-1013.0-1015.23), **Hence `document_end` will run before the time that `document_start` would have run?**

Comment: @Pacerier 1) you cannot remove a listener if you don't know the name of the function; 2) plus, the page doesn't know anything about your script, since that extension scripts run in a separated context and don't share any variable with the scripts in the page. So the answer is no.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, But the page can do `document.replaceChild(n=document.createElement('html'),document.documentElement);n.innerHTML='replacer'` if your script is at document_start. On the other hand, if you put  at document_idle, he wouldn't be able to replace your injected listeners.

Comment: @Xan, Ah I'v realized now. That "[CSS](http://archive.is/m7For#selection-5667.63-5669.3)" does not refer to <style> and <link rel> but refers only to CSS injected by manifest.