# listen head load event in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to inject a css file before user can view (first style is blank, second is black, so you see the change) .

To do this, I load my content js on document_start.

But I can't add a listener on the head element because it doesn't exist (=null) .

So I am searching a way to catch the onload event of the head tag .

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186349/chrome-extension-set-to-run-at-document-start-is-running-too-fast) question and it's accepted answer. The DOM content isn't loaded already on `document_start`, but the `document` object of JavaScript is.

So what you can do is listen on the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event, which fires as soon as the DOM is loaded.

This is an example how your content script could look like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) instead, which can be accessed at the time of `document_start`, see this thread for more details: [chromium-extensions/tyAm1GAY-I4](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/tyAm1GAY-I4)

`manifest.json`

```json
{
    "name": "36695983",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "content.css"
    ]
}
```

`content.js`

```js
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = chrome.runtime.getURL("content.css");
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.documentElement.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: and how to add script tag in the head ? The document.head object is null ... I'm trying with MutationObserver for the moment

Comment: @thib3113, maybe I misunderstood that, so you want to insert a css into current web page while the page is not under your control? I thought the page is yours so you can include a script tag directly in the html

Comment: @thib3113, you could use `document.documentElement` instead, see updated answer.

Comment: I can't update the html file, I'm not the owner of the website . I don't undestand your answer .... I'had found a way, so I will update

Comment: @thib3113, I have updated my answer, `content.js` would be loaded before the dom is constructed, and just use `document.documentElement.appendChild(your css tag)` to inject your css, which happens before "user can view"

Answer (score 0):

I use this :

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (!mutation.addedNodes) return
    for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
      // do things to your newly added nodes here
      var node = mutation.addedNodes[i];
      if(node.nodeName == "HEAD"){
        //make stuff when head load

        //don't forget to stop listener
        observer.disconnect();        
      }
    }
  })
})

observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true
  , subtree: true
  , attributes: false
  , characterData: false
})
```